# VMware alerts are not sending an email

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I am running vCenter 6.0 appliance that is managing two ESXi hosts. I want to get emails when the alarm is red. I've set SMTP server and sender account that is going to send emails (vCenter Server settings -> email), but emails are not getting to me. 
Also, I find it weird that only vCenter requires only info about SMTP server and server account, I'm wondering where is field for password, port, etc.

Comment: You need to add the recipient email addresses to the Alarm actions.

Comment: I added it from the first time. That part is clear. But emails are not arriving.

Comment: Added it where? On the Alarms?

Comment: Yes, to the alarms. That part is clear. I've added recipient email to the specific alarm and I've added SMTP server and sender account to the vCenter Settings. I've tested it on Alarm for datastore usage on disk, and the Alarm is red (I've put low threshold) but email notifications are not comming. I've followed these tutorials: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.solutions.doc%2FGUID-2888F032-22A4-49C1-B27E-45F073E7C785.html and http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018029

Answer (score -2):

I have not used vCenter specifically but these kind of limited settings for SMTP that you mention may indicate you need to allow anonymous access from the vCenter appliance on your SMTP server. This [VMware article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004070) mentions checking that, among other things.